# Random generation of points for the graphs of 3 stock share parameters

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, typescript, classes

I currently studying **OOP and related design patterns**, and tried to implement random data generation for some stock charts using OOP as an exercise.

This code randomly generates data points for 3 parameters (share price, spread and yield), so it later can be used as an input for the graphs.

I want to receive some feedback on how to make this code more SOLID and in accordance with OOP best practices in general. Have I used the proper design patterns?

```
import { faker } from "@faker-js/faker";
import {
    addDays,
    eachDayOfInterval,
    subMonths,
    isAfter,
    subWeeks,
    subYears,
    startOfWeek,
    startOfMonth,
    startOfQuarter,
    startOfYear,
} from "date-fns";

const MIN_YEARS = 1.5;
const MAX_YEARS = 6;
// Oriented on SP500 shares to get the hardcoded numbers  in USD
const MIN_SHARE_PRICE = 300;
const MAX_SHARE_PRICE = 5000;
// Googled that 4 is maximum number of decimal places for share prices
const SHARE_PRICE_FIXED_PRECISION = 6;
// Yield and spread are in percents
const MIN_YIELD = 0.1;
const MAX_YIELD = 0.5;
const YIELD_PRECISION = 0.0001;
const MIN_SPREAD = 0.12;
const MAX_SPREAD = 0.2;
const SPREAD_PRECISION = 0.0001;

const CHANGE_FACTOR = 0.03;

type TimeIntervaleOption = "week" | "month" | "quarter" | "year" | "max";

type ShareParameter = {
    yield: number;
    spread: number;
    price: number;
};

class DataPoint {
    id: string;
    date: Date;
    parameters: ShareParameter;

    constructor(id: string, date: Date, parameters: ShareParameter) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}

class Share {
    public readonly name: string;
    public readonly ISIN: string;
    private _dataPoints: DataPoint[];

    get dataPoints() {
        return this._dataPoints;
    }

    constructor(name: string, ISIN: string, dataPoints: DataPoint[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ISIN = ISIN;
        this._dataPoints = dataPoints;
    }
}

class ShareFactory {
    private static _nextIdNumber = 0;
    private static get nextIdNumber() {
        return ShareFactory._nextIdNumber++;
    }

    static createShare(name: string, ISIN: string): Share {
        const dataPoints = ShareFactory.generateDataPoints(ISIN);
        return new Share(name, ISIN, dataPoints);
    }

    static generateDataPoints(ISIN: string): DataPoint[] {
        // how many years the stock exists
        const years = faker.number.float({ min: MIN_YEARS, max: MAX_YEARS });

        // let's niglect leap years difference for simplicity
        const startDate = addDays(new Date(), -years * 365);
        const endDate = new Date();
        let previousDataPointPrice = parseFloat(
            faker.finance.amount(MIN_SHARE_PRICE, MAX_SHARE_PRICE, SHARE_PRICE_FIXED_PRECISION)
        );
        let previousDataPointYield = faker.number.float({
            min: MIN_YIELD,
            max: MAX_YIELD,
            precision: YIELD_PRECISION,
        });
        let previousDataPointSpread = faker.number.float({
            min: MIN_SPREAD,
            max: MAX_SPREAD,
            precision: SPREAD_PRECISION,
        });

        const days = eachDayOfInterval({ start: startDate, end: endDate });

        const dataPoints = days.map((date: Date) => {
            const changeFactor = faker.number.float({
                min: 1 - CHANGE_FACTOR,
                max: 1 + CHANGE_FACTOR,
            });
            const newPrice = parseFloat(
                (previousDataPointPrice * changeFactor).toFixed(SHARE_PRICE_FIXED_PRECISION)
            );
            const newYield = previousDataPointYield * changeFactor;
            const newSpread = previousDataPointSpread * changeFactor;

            previousDataPointPrice = newPrice;
            previousDataPointYield = newYield;
            previousDataPointSpread = newSpread;

            return new DataPoint(ISIN + ShareFactory.nextIdNumber, date, {
                yield: newYield,
                spread: newSpread,
                price: newPrice,
            });
        });

        return dataPoints;
    }
}

class ShareFilterService {
    static filterDataPointsByTime(share: Share, timeInterval?: TimeIntervaleOption): DataPoint[] {
        const now = new Date();
        let startDate: Date;

        switch (timeInterval) {
            case "week":
                startDate = startOfWeek(subWeeks(now, 1));
                break;
            case "month":
                startDate = startOfMonth(subMonths(now, 1));
                break;
            case "quarter":
                startDate = startOfQuarter(subMonths(now, 3));
                break;
            case "year":
                startDate = startOfYear(subYears(now, 1));
                break;
            default: // corresponds to 'max'
                startDate = new Date(
                    Math.min(...share.dataPoints.map((dataPoint) => dataPoint.date.getTime()))
                );
        }

        return share.dataPoints.filter((dataPoint) => isAfter(dataPoint.date, startDate));
    }
}

class ShareRepository {
    private readonly _sharePool: Map<string, Share> = new Map();

    constructor(private shareFactory: typeof ShareFactory) {}

    getShareByISIN(ISIN: string): Share | null {
        return this._sharePool.get(ISIN) || null;
    }

    createShare(name?: string, ISIN?: string): void {
        if (ISIN && !this._sharePool.has(ISIN)) {
            const actualName = name || faker.company.name();
            const actualISIN =
                ISIN ||
                faker.string.alpha({ length: 2 }).toUpperCase() +
                    faker.string.alphanumeric(10).toUpperCase() +
                    faker.number.int(1);
            const share = this.shareFactory.createShare(actualName, actualISIN);
            this._sharePool.set(share.ISIN, share);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Share with this ISIN already exists");
        }
    }
}

const repo = new ShareRepository(ShareFactory);
repo.createShare("US1234567890");
const share = repo.getShareByISIN("US1234567890");

if (share) {
    const filteredDataPoints = ShareFilterService.filterDataPointsByTime(share, "week");
    console.log(filteredDataPoints && filteredDataPoints[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**nextIdNumber**

The method returns the current `_nextIdNumber`, not the next.
`++` suffix uses the variable's value then increments.

```
   private static get nextIdNumber() {
    return ShareFactory._nextIdNumber++;
}
```

For *next* value use:  `++_nextIdNumber`

---

Defining constants is excellent. Looks like these are used only by `shareFactory` so put them there. It makes a more [coherent class and reduces coupling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3085285/463206); also it gets them out of global scope

---

> OOP is not necessary here

OOP's goals and purposes certainly are. And SOLID, as a nemonic, certainly does not encapsulate near the entirety of OOP principles and practice.

It is hard to fully appreciate the revolution that is OOP without having experienced a complex application written in something pre-OOP (like COBOL). Indeed when a Norwegian team found it impossible to model the complexity of cargo shipping, they stopped the project and invented [Simula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula) then continued on the project using Simula.

And I must say that OOP is not mutually exclusive to nor incompatible with functional programming as current debates imply.

---

**Factory Pattern**

Design patterns are as much about intent as their particular designs. Some patterns have virtually identical design but with slight differences motivated by their differing intent. The Factory is about creating differently typed objects with the specific type deferred to the factory. Typically we mean subclasses implementing an API.

Instantiating objects of only one type would be done in a constructor. In this case we might encapsulate complex construction via methods or even use a separate class - this is good OOP but is not The Factory Pattern.

Study the "construction" design patterns for their differing purposes and design.

Comment: Thanks for you comments! 

I said that OOP is not necessary here because I expected to receive comments that example is too simple for OOP, so I mentioned that I understand it in advance and it's solely for learning purposes.

Also I was not sure about wrapping singe `filterDataPointsByTime` function into a wrapper-class `ShareFilterService` because it's a single function not a collection. Maybe it would be better to leave it as a function? And how to properly name such class? Is naming utility function collection classes so they end with Service a common practice?

Comment: What does mean "typed deferred to the factory" in this context? Does it mean that exact type of an instance is given to the factory explicitly, or that factory should determine it itself from some  arguments the factory been called with?

Comment: *... is too simple for OOP*  =>  I'm gobsmacked; speechless [So watch this video](https://youtu.be/8bZh5LMaSmE?si=HGpei2vnqEF6gCmM). It is understandable and the lessons universal.  Sandy Metz is a fantastic explainer. At time 35:12 :  "compexity has gone down by 75% because I made many small objects"

Comment: *type deferred to the factory* =>  `myFactory.create(<what>)`   "what" is an argument telling what class-object to make. What is that?; an enum or unique combo of properties or ... whatever.

Comment: @pacmaninbw this code creates random points for a graphs of a stock share (it's price and 2 other parameters). It does it by multiplying previous value by a random multiplier from 0.95 to 1.05. I mentioned it a bit in the question description. If it's not clear I can update the quesion. For generating random stuff it uses faker.js library.